# Downloading a huge image onto Android (6144x32768)

Tags: java, android, image, download, android-download-manager

We're trying to download an [image](http://training-slides.com/slides-image/slide-one.jpeg) onto android so it can be viewed in an App. We can load it fine, but can't download it due to the fact it due to memory issues. The image is 9MB however the resolution is so huge I imagine it's an issue with how Android reads it in?

Tried:
   Writing straight to SD 
   Picasso 
   OpenStream

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

And the error:

```
Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 805306380 byte allocation with 8329762 free bytes and 180MB until OOM
```

We need to actually download the image, however.

Comment: So what is your question? Can't download the image? Don't you know how to display a chunk of the image?

Comment: We are getting a Out Of Memory issue when actually downloading the image from the server and decoding it. We are using BitmapFactory.decodestream

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: This might help: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: That's the main code, it works fine for smaller images, but the way it appears to read it in causes it to become much larger (I believe) so we're desperately hoping for a work around

Comment: The issue we are having is the download of the image not the displaying of the image, if we manually place the image in the folder of the phone we do not have any problems loading the file.

Comment: I tried your code on my device (by the way it looks like you did a bad copy-paste job, the decodeStream line is not valid) and it works fine, as long as I properly pass the options object with inJustDecodeBounds set to true. My suggestion is to double check the actual code in your file. Why are you returning myBitmap? That object will always be null when inJustDecodeBounds is set to true.

Comment: Sorry, the code was actually a previous hashed attempt I've updated the code again. Were you actually able to download the linked image? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ok now I see, the code as you've written it won't work. That's because you are trying to decode the entire JPEG at full resolution. This creates an in-memory ARGB bitmap which takes 6k * 32k * 4 = 800 megabytes. You should instead download the JPG to a temporary file; use inJustDecodeBounds first to get the size; then decode it using a proper inSampleSize multiplier. Please check the documentation for BitmapFactory.Options.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that's what the problem could be! Unfortunately we can't subsample it as we need to retain it's high quality. The image view loads fine when we copy it across via USB. We just need to download it. (If that hopefully makes sense)

Comment: I don't see how USB would make a difference. What is likely happening is that when you are copying it over USB your file is being reencoded on the fly by Android's MTP handler to a lower resolution that actually loads. If you really need the full resolution you can use something like BitmapRegionDecoder and decode regions of the bitmap at a time with a user interface that allows the user to navigate between regions. You are not going to be able to load that entire bitmap in memory at once without downsampling or using regions.

Comment: It seems to retain the high resolution via USB but obviously not by subsampling. We're using https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view to display it.

Answer (score 0):

A 6k by 32k image will take roughly 800 MB in memory when fully loaded, as ARGB bitmaps require 4 bytes per pixel.

The reason it is working when you are copying it over USB is likely because Android transcodes huge images to a size suitable for phone display when they are copied over with MTP.

You can use downsampling (the `Bitmap.Options.inSampleSize` parameter), or the `BitmapRegionDecoder` to downsample or show a partial region of the image.

Another option is a library such as [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) that can handle all of this for you, such as with the following code:

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri("http://training-slides.com/slides-image/slide-one.jpeg"));
```

Once the image loads in the image view, you can use pinch-to-zoom and touch panning to navigate around the image.

Comment: That is the library we're using, having tried your code we get: Failed to initialise bitmap decoder
11-06 03:39:55.592 19690-21365/com.training_slides.www.slides E/SubsamplingScaleImageView: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://training-slides.com/slides-image/slide-one.jpeg

Comment: Yep it looks like it can't load images directly from HTTP uris. Try copying the file first from the HTTP source to a temporary file, then feeding the path to the file into the SubsamplingScaleImageView.